# How to export a Java Game in Eclipse?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, export

I've been writing a platform game in the Slick2D, the Java game library, using the Eclipse IDE. How do I export my game & external libraries & resource folder into a runnable JAR so that other people can play my game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click your project on the package explorer and choose "export". Then use the search to locate the option "Runnable JAR file" under "Java".

Choose your output path and JAR name. Use the dropdown above to define the class with your main(String[])-method. You need to have a run configuration defined (which often happens automatically when you run a new class directly in Eclipse) in order for the dropdown to be populated.

Below the name selection there is a radio selector, that you can use to select "Package required libraries into generated JAR", which instructs Eclipse to do just that.